# Prevent displaying or selecting duplicate values combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 5 comboboxes, say each with a list of values `{1,2,3,4,5}`. I initially set a distinct value to each of them so it looks like so:

`CmbBox1 - selected item - 1`

`CmbBox2 - selected item - 2`

`CmbBox3 - selected item - 3`

`CmbBox4 - selected item - 4`

`CmbBox5 - selected item - 5`

Now I want to make it so when I select `3` in `CmbBox1`, it will auto change the value in `CmbBox3` to `1`, since I'm not allowing duplicates.

My problem is which event I should subscribe for that.

My basic reasoning is I keep the old value, assign new value, check the other boxes for new value, if it exists, replace with old value.

I tried subscribing to `SelectedValueChanged` and `DropDownClosed` events, but they seem to not keep the old value, so I get a null error.

Which event should I subscribe to?

Comment: did you try SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: Did you try to keep a record which element is selected in which combo box, for example with an array or such? Then you can use the events you tried and look up the old value in that array...

Comment: @BojanB yes but what event would manage the array of old values refreshing? It's back to square one it seems.

Comment: You have to manage the array in the `SelectedValueChanged` event. You would have an event for each combo box, so you know which array item is being changed. When the change occurs you change the item in the array as well and you search for the duplicate and change the array value as well as the combo box  value for the duplicate.